# Javascript window["functionName"](arguments) returns "is not a function" TypeError

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, eval

Im trying to run an AJAX function based on which tab is currently active in my app. everything works fine when I call the function after certain events but I'm unable to invoke the function using a string variable, dynamically.

following this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/359910/5950111 I just receive a TypeError describing that the object Im calling is not a function.

this is my ajax function:

```
function home_tab_fetchMore(items_count) {
    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let output = []
    request.open('GET', `feedstream/${items_count}`);
    request.onload = function () {
        if (request.status === 200 && request.responseText != '') {
            let new_items = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
            for (let i = 0; i < new_items.length; i++) {
                let item = new_items[i];
                let event_id = feed_stream_row.children.length + 1;
                let feed_item = htmlToElement(`
                        <div class="grid-item" id="eventcard_${event_id}">
                        <div class="card-header">Featured</div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">${item.fields['title']}</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">${item.fields['appointment']}
                        <br>
                        ${dummy_text.sentence(5, 40)}
                        </p>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    `);
                // appending new item to DOM and updating masonry laytout
                feed_stream_row.appendChild(feed_item);
                msnry.appended(feed_item);
                output.push(feed_item);
            }
        } else {
            console.log('no response!');
        }
    };
    request.send();
    return output;
};
```

and this is the caller event:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height()) {
        var fnstring = `${current_active_tab().id}_fetchMore`;
        var fn = window[fnstring]

        console.log(typeof(fnstring)) // returns: string type
        console.log(fnstring) // returns: home_tab_fetchMore without quotes
        console.log(fn) // returns: undefined

        fn(2) // returns: Uncaught TypeError: fn is not a function

        // however, this line works just as expected:
        home_tab_fetchMore(2)
    };
});
```

There are also additional lines to the TypeError that I can't comprehend:

```
Uncaught TypeError: fn is not a function
at main.js:128
at dispatch (jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2)
at v.handle (jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2)
```

I appreciate any suggestion and guidance in advance, thank you.

Comment: replace function declaration with function expression `home_tab_fetchMore = function (items_count) {`

Comment: @Praveen you are a Life Saver! thank you indeed. why don't you add that as an answer so I can choose as the solution?

Comment: `return output;` that's not going to work because async

Comment: @James it actually works and I don't understand why. I used to have a headache with this one too but somehow managed to get it work. now it returns an array of html elements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function home_tab_fetchMore(items_count) {}
```

The above function definition won't be available in `window` object unless it is called.  Instead do with function expression(You can't use function expressions before you define them).

```
home_tab_fetchMore = function() {} OR
window.home_tab_fetchMore = function() {}
```